# How to know TimeZone difference to UTC?

Tags: java, timezone

I want to know how I can recuperate **GMT +1** from `java.util.TimeZone`. For example I have `TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid")` and I want to know that value is **GMT +1** or `TimeZone.getTimeZone("Atlantic/Canary")` is **GMT**.

Comment: Do you mean like `TimeZone.getOffset(time);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getOffset` method. This method requires a `long date` as it takes account of daylight savings etc.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final TimeZone madrid = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid");
    final TimeZone canaries = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Atlantic/Canary");
    final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println(madrid.getOffset(now));
    System.out.println(canaries.getOffset(now));
}
```

As you can see this returns the offset in millis

```
7200000
3600000
```

You can then use `TimeUnit` to convert to hours:

```
System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(madrid.getOffset(now)));
System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(canaries.getOffset(now)));
```

Output:

```
2
1
```

Answer (score 3):

As the question has been already answered , but still a friendly suggestion use [Joda Date Time API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) , it is very powerful and covers all the limitation that was there in JDK Date and Time classes.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The getOffset method returns the difference in milliseconds.

Note that these time zones also use DST, their current offset from UTC is 2 and 1 hours respectively.